# Azure APIM Premium - Number of requests can handle

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We are building an Ecom app which will relay on Azure APIM, we expect 66.5 million requests per day. In a pick hours, it would be 10 million requests. Can Azure APIM Premium handle such a load? At present we have 8 scale units, is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management) the estimated maximum throughput is 4000 rps. If you have 8 scale units the estimated maximum throughput is

32.000 rps
1.9m rpm
115.2 rph

You can have up to 12 scale units so you should be safe to handle such a load. (You can call to have > 12 scale units if needed)